# autogenerating ".uuid" files in linux directory

Tags: linux, fonts, debian, uuid

OS - Debian Stable

I downloaded fonts from a website (that seemed legitimate to me) and transferred the contents to `/usr/share/fonts/directory`. There's a `.uuid` file being generated for every directory with a string like this as its sole content:

`f25e9432-c6f1-4bbe-a33c-89289a8d17f1`

This file regenerates right after I delete it. Is this a malicious program? Is this indexing by the OS itself or is it something like `fc-cache` running in the background? What could be the cause of this?

Comment: What I observed is it's Synaptic or `xfsettingsd` (in case of XFCE) scanning fonts directories.

Comment: I'm using XFCE, if that matters.

Is it the same for you?

Comment: I think it doesn't matter. Behavior should be identical on all DEs and all distros which use `fontconfig` package for font management. `fontconfig` generates `.uuid` files for caching purpose to speed up GUI loading time. Any packages linking to `fontconfig` may trigger a scan of system-wide and user-specific font directories. I observed two as stated above. Synaptic is run manually with root privilges, so creates `.uuid` files in all font directories. `xfsettingsd` runs with non-root user UID, so continuously watches user-specific directories only while running as daemon.

Comment: It seems UUID phenomenon is dropped: https://lists.freedesktop.org/archives/fontconfig/2018-October/006374.html, so this won't happen in future releases.

Comment: Nope. The .uuid files are still being created on a fresh install of Mint 20.2. After installing TeX and other font-oriented software I ran fc-cache and it created them in every directory visited. Doesn't matter particularly, but it sure hasn't been dropped yet.

Answer (score 2):

This has nothing to do with the fact that you've downloaded your own fonts. This is simply just `fontconfig`doing it's job. It very well could just be the cached data created. Only rather, the binary data is being converted into a uuid string/unique ID.

So, I would say no. I do not believe this to be the cause of anything malicious. Nor are any of these occurrences a result from you downloading fonts from your web browser.